# Importing REDCAP data with repeating instruments

Tags: tableau-desktop, redcap

I connected Redcap to Tableau using Web Data Connector.

Due to having a repeating instrument, i am getting the same record id multiple times and null values where the variable names are not in the same instrument.

Can anyone help me in showing the data without getting null values ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc3SS.png)

I tried to put the 'record Id' at the far left to order by it and moved the a 'civil ID' on the right.

I want to get the information from the repeating instrument in a sub division.
The problem is that it is registering null values for the civil ID in the repeating instrument.

Comment: Your data looks like that typical of a UNION, could you update your question with the SQL you are using to pull this data?

Answer (score 0):

The Tableau Data Connector gets data from your REDCap project via the REDCap API, so your data are exported exacty as they are if you did an "All Data" or report download from REDCap's Data Export module. You get one row per record per instance.

| record_id | redcap_repeat_instrument | redcap_repeat_instance | nonrptvar1 | var2nonrptvar2 | rptvar1 | rptvar2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  | a | b |  |  |
| 1 | repeating_form | 1 |  |  | x | y |
| 1 | repeating_form | 1 |  |  | p | q |

There may be some manipulation you need to do on the Tableau side to get this formatted according ot yiour needs. I'm sorry I'm not a Tableau user though, so can't help with that bit.